# Trouble decoding string after using uri_escape_utf8

Tags: perl, utf-8, urlencode

In Perl I am encrypting a string and then using uri_escape_utf8 so I can send it in a URL.  I then receive what appears to be the exact same encoded string back to Perl but can't figure out to decode it.

I've created a simple test program in Perl:

```
 $encodedUsername = uri_escape_utf8(encrypter($u));
 $enc = Encode::decode('utf8', uri_unescape($encodedUsername));
 $final = unencrypter($enc);
```

doesn't work, $final is an empty string.

If I do a regular uri_escape instead of uri_escaps_utf8 it all works fine.  But I need to do uri_escape_utf8 to be compatible withy Jaascript's encodeURIcomponent.

What am I missing?

Thanks!  - Jon

Background: I am using blowfish encryption on a string and then using uri_escape_utf8 so I can send the string in a URL.  The receiver is a javascript program which uses encodeURIComponent to send back the encoded string to a Perl program.  encodeURIComponent is supposed to be equivalent to uri_eacape_utf8.

```
 my $mykeyS = <secret key>; 
 my $len = 8;
 my $mS = Crypt::CBC->new( -literal_key  => 1,
                     -key       => $mykeyS,
                     -iv        => $iv8,
                     -keysize   => $len,
                     -cipher    => 'Blowfish',
                     -header    => 'none'
 );

 sub encrypter{
   my ($val) = @_;

   if (length $val < 8) {
     $val = pack('A8', $val);
   }
 return $mS->encrypt($val);
 }

 sub unencrypter {
    my ($valEncrypted) = @_;

    eval {
       $val = $mS->decrypt($valEncrypted);
       if (length $val == 8) {
          $val = unpack('A8', $val);
       }
    };
    if ($@) {
       $val = '';
    }
    return $val;
 }
```

Comment: Clarification question: how are `encrypter` and `unencrypter` defined?

Comment: blowfish doesn't return text, so I question whether it makes sense to use uri_escape_utf8, but there's no reason why it wouldn't work. And you haven't demonstrated that it doesn't. The problem could just as likely be in in `unencrypter`. There's nothing we can do with this question without more info.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Rather than messing with uri_escape_utf8, I'm using

```
 use MIME::Base64 qw(encode_base64url decode_base64url);
 encode_base64url(encrypter($u));  # to encode
 unencrypter(decode_base64url($p1)); # to decode
```

So far it's working great!